# Foursquare API - Has there been a change to the core venue field specials?

Tags: foursquare

Has there been a change to the core venue field specials?

I'm using Venue Detail request (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) to retrieve Venue Detail.  As usual this request returns a "venue" for a response field.

What seems to have changed is the core venue field "specials".  This now appears to be returning the same response fields as Specials/list ( https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/specials/list).

This requires iteration on specials.items as opposed to specials.

Looking at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue the Core venue field "specials" still should be returned as an array.

I'm trying to find in the change log where this may have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The venues specials object is now using the standard count and items format that other lists in the api use.

The new format is only for clientversion 20120120 and later.  Older versions get the old format.

We'll be updating the docs/changelog shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's exactly what I was looking for.

In the future it would be great if changes like this were published ahead of time... actually I think most times it is, maybe this one just slipped through the cracks.

Thanks again!